# -bash: minikube: command not found

Tags: macos, homebrew, minikube

I'm trying to follow [Install Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/#install-minikube) and even though there are no errors during install, I still unable to run it:

```
$ brew install minikube
Updating Homebrew...
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/minikube-1.5.2.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/alexus/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/a466d3b5c7208788bb6a82fa4de4576440dbfa3b7b5b1d4ddb48cb9a3d44f1e9--minikube-1.5.2.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring minikube-1.5.2.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
==> minikube cask is installed, skipping link.
==> Caveats
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d

zsh completions have been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/minikube/1.5.2: 8 files, 51.5MB
$ minikube
-bash: minikube: command not found
$
```

Please advise.

---

```
$ sudo mv minikube /usr/local/bin
Password:
mv: rename minikube to /usr/local/bin/minikube: No such file or directory
$
```

`minikube version`:

```
$ /usr/local/Cellar/minikube/1.5.2/bin/minikube version
minikube version: v1.5.2
commit: 792dbf92a1de583fcee76f8791cff12e0c9440ad
$
```

Comment: Your mv command is wrong.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try using

```
brew link minikube
```

which solved the issue for me. After installing `minikube` using `Homebrew` (`brew install minikube`) we need to run the above command which will create **symlinks** for us. Then the `minikube` command works fine.

Comment: `brew link minikube
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/minikube/1.14.2` ... `minikube version`: `minikube version: v1.14.2
commit: 2c82918e2347188e21c4e44c8056fc80408bce10` ... `minicube start` : 
`-bash: minicube: command not found` - any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

This looks like an issue with your path:

- Restart the terminal.
- Did you add minikube to the path per the documentation?

> Here’s an easy way to add the Minikube executable to your path: `sudo
>   mv minikube /usr/local/bin`

- Verify the path with `which minikube`.

**Edited to address new info in questions**:

This is still a path issue.  It appears that your install went to `/usr/local/Cellar/minikube/1.5.2` not `/usr/local/bin/minikube`.  The different aliases are looking for the latter directory which is why this is not working for you.  You should move the directory as per the documentation so that the scripts with the various shortcuts can find the proper link.

Comment: I updated my question with that step, I believe that step applies for `stand-alone binary` only and not for brew package.

Comment: Restarting the terminal sufficed for me.

Answer (score 1):

my way of solving this:

```
$ cd /usr/local/Cellar/minikube/
$ sudo ln -s 1.5.2 current
Password:
$ cd /usr/local/bin/
$ ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/minikube/current/bin/minikube 
$ 
$ minikube version
minikube version: v1.5.2
commit: 792dbf92a1de583fcee76f8791cff12e0c9440ad
$
```

Comment: I get `minikube version: v1.14.2` but ALSO STILL get `minicube start` ... 
`-bash: minicube: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

This helped me on ubuntu:

```
sudo ln /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/minikube/1.28.0/bin/minikube /usr/local/bin
```

To discover if your path to minikube differs, use:

```
$ brew link minikube
```